# recommendation pattern to use for handling sessions per web requests in mvc using NHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, session-per-request

For example.
My session factory is located in MyDomain.SessionProvider class.
Session can be open `using ISession session = SessionProvider.Instance.OpenSession()`

**Step: SessionProvider.cs**

```
public static SessionProvider Instance { get; private set; }
        private static ISessionFactory _SessionFactory;

        static SessionProvider()
        {
            var provider = new SessionProvider();
            provider.Initialize();
            Instance = provider;
        }

        private SessionProvider()
        {

        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            string csStringName = "ConnectionString";
            var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
               //ommiting mapping and db conf.

                .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web"))
                .BuildConfiguration();
            _SessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

        }

        public ISession OpenSession()
        {
            return _SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        public ISession GetCurrentSession()
        {
            return _SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        }
```

**Step: Global.asax.cs**

```
public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; private set; }
```

Application Start

```
SessionFactory = SessionProvider.Instance.OpenSession().SessionFactory;
```

App_BeginRequest

```
var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
```

EndRequest
dispose session

```
var session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
session.Dispose();
```

**Step3.HomeController**
I should be using current session like

```
var session = SessionProvider.Instance.GetCurrentSession();
using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction())
{
   //retrieve data from session
}
```

Now, with trying to retrieve data on my controller like desc. in  Step3. I got error message that my session is closed. I tried to remove Application_EndRequest block inside global.asax cause my transaction is wrapped with session but with no success. Still same error.

Second/side question: is this pattern accepted widely, or it is better to wrapped inside custom attributes on mvc controllers. Thanks.

Updated:
On my controller when try to instantiate current session in line

```
var session = SessionProvider.Instance.GetCurrentSession();
```

I'm getting following error:

```
**Connection = 'session.Connection' threw an exception of type 'NHibernate.HibernateException'**

**base {System.ApplicationException} = {"Session is closed"}**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @LeftyX

I solved this problem using TekPub video Mastering NHibernate with some customizations.

Global.asax

```
//Whenever the request from page comes in (single request for a page)
//open session and on request end close the session.

public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory =
   MyDomain.SessionProvider.CreateSessionFactory();

public MvcApplication() 
{
    this.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(MvcApplication_BeginRequest);
    this.EndRequest +=new EventHandler(MvcApplication_EndRequest);
}

private void MvcApplication_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory).Dispose();
}

private void MvcApplication_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(SessionFactory.OpenSession());
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    SessionFactory.OpenSession();
}
```

and inside my controller

```
 var session = MvcApplication.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
 {
     using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
      {... omitting retrieving data}
 }
```

Comment: Simple, clean solution that is perfectly adequate for small applications. For more complex scenarios you might want to take a look at IoC frameworks with good NHibernate integration, such as Castle Windsor or Spring.NET, with declarative transaction management. The effort has to pay off, though, so stick with your simple approach for simple applications.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a couple of simple and easy implementations [here](http://ayende.com/blog/4101/do-you-need-a-framework) and [here](http://ayende.com/blog/4805/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-limiting-session-scope) and find some code [here](https://github.com/ayende/NHibernate-London-May).
I like Ayende's approach to keep everything simple and clean:

```
public class Global: System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

    protected static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return new Configuration()
            .Configure(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "hibernate.cfg.xml"))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession CurrentSession
    {
        get{ return (ISession)HttpContext.Current.Items["current.session"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Items["current.session"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Global()
    {
        BeginRequest += delegate
        {
            CurrentSession = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        };
        EndRequest += delegate
        {
            if(CurrentSession != null)
                CurrentSession.Dispose();
        };
    }
}
```

In my projects I've decided to use a IoC container (StructureMap).
In case you're interested you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204611/using-nhibernate-with-both-mysql-server-and-microsoft-sql-server-2008/9213847#9213847).