# Update NHiberbate Connection String in App.config

Tags: c#, nhibernate, configuration, connection-string, app-config

I use NHibernate in my c# project to save data to database as well as to retrieve it. There is nhibernate-configuration section in in app.config which includes NHibernate-related properties. However I need to use connection string from a different source and the problem is to update this property in app.config during runtime. Is that possible? Can I somehow update property "connection.connection_string"?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly I think that what you need is several session factories. I don't think you can change this connection string on-the-fly, but either way it is not the best solution.

Here you have some example of how you can achieve it:
[How to use NHibernate with both MySQL server and Microsoft SQL server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204611/how-to-use-nhibernate-with-both-mysql-server-and-microsoft-sql-server-2008/9213847#9213847)